# How to compare the values $\sqrt 2$ and $\ln(3).$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

How to compare the values $\sqrt 2$ and $\ln(3)?$ I know only $\ln(x)<x$ and $\sqrt{x}<x$. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Compare $\sqrt x$ and $\ln(1+x)$ by using calculus techniques to analyze their difference.

Comment: Also, $\sqrt{1/2}>1/2$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**"Argument" 1**

Compute: $\sqrt{2}\approx 1.41421356237$ ([source](https://www.google.com/search?q=sqrt(2))) and $\ln(3) \approx 1.09861228867$ ([source](https://www.google.com/#q=ln(3)))

There's no way floating point arithmetic is *that* inaccurate, so the desired inequality is true by direct computation. :)

But beware floating point arithmetic when you desire high levels of precision!

```
$python
>>> .1 + .2 == .3
False
>>> .1 + .2
0.30000000000000004
```

---

**Argument 2**

Surely we can do better than a black box calculator. Motivated by how a calculator might carry out a direct computation, we argue via numerical approximation ...

As the exponential function is monotone, the desired comparison is equivalent to comparing $e^{\sqrt{2}}$ to $3$. The number $3$ is easy to compute, so we focus on the left side of the equation. From the calculator, we suspect that $e^\sqrt{2} > 3$, so we are led to truncate the exponential series:
\begin{align*}
e^\sqrt{2} &= 1 + \sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{2!}\sqrt{2}^2 + \frac{1}{3!}\sqrt{2}^3 + \cdots \\
&\geq 1 + \sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}^2 \\
&= 2 + \sqrt{2} \\
&> 2 + 1 \\
&= 3
\end{align*}

---

**Argument 3**

Motivated by graphing the functions:
[image: graphing often provides insight]
The square root starts ahead of the logarithm and doesn't look back -- it not only is greater, its rate of increase is also greater, and so we can reason from their derivatives.

Let $F(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $G(x) = \ln(1+x)$. Notice that both functions are smooth on $(0,\infty)$ and have 
$$F(x) = \int_0^x\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\ dt$$
and
$$G(x) = \int_0^x \frac{1}{t+1}\ dt $$
Now observe that
$$ 2\sqrt{t} \leq t+1 $$
with equality achieved at $t=1$, as $2\sqrt{t}$ is concave down and the function $t\mapsto t+1$ is the equation of the tangent line of $2\sqrt{t}$ at $t=1$.

Therefore $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}} \geq \frac{1}{t+1} > 0$ for all $t>0$. As integrating positive functions preserves inequality, we have $F(x) \geq G(x)$ for all $x>0$. In particular, $F(2) \geq G(2)$, so $\sqrt{2}\geq \ln(3)$.

Comment: in argument 1 it isn't log(3) but ln(3). You have right decimal value for ln(3).

Comment: @MaxW At some point I think most people abandon the notation $\ln$ and write $\log = \log_e$, since the natural logarithm is the most common and, well, natural log (unless you're in comp sci?). Nevertheless, I changed it just to be clear. :)

Comment: @MaxW "$\log$" can mean any base in general. Of course he means $\ln$. People have tried to standardise it to $\ln$, $\lg$ and $\mathrm{lb}$ but it hasn't completely taken off.

Comment: I totally understand I'm being picky. I'd agree that $\text{log}_e$ can be used for $\text{ln}$, but $\text{log}$ with no subscript is understood to mean a log to the base 10. // I just didn't like a good answer marred by a brain fart.

Comment: @MaxW log is commonly used in place of ln and it is in general not understood to be in base 10. If there is something to be picky about here it would be to use the  same notation as in the question.

Answer (score 9):

With simple numerical calculation we can show $\ln(3)< \frac75<\sqrt2$.

First calculate $e^{7/5}$ using the series expansion for exponential function.

Taking just three terms of the series: $e^{7/5}> 1+ 7/5 + 7^2/(2!5^2)=169/50>3$
This shows natural log for 3 is less than 7/5.

Now $7^2/5^2=49/25<2$ And we are done.

Comment: I think you mean $e^{7/5}>$ not $e^{7/5}<$.

Comment: Good solution regardless.

Comment: Thanks Jam. I corrected the error.

Comment: Perhaps this solution needs some explanation, not just proof. If the two numbers are different there must exist some number in between. And it can be chosen to be a rational number, by their denseness.  Experience with rational approximations for $\sqrt2$ had taught me $7/5$ is an approximation with < 5% error. I calculated and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to look at $f(x) = \sqrt{x} - \ln(1+x)$.

Note that for $x = 1$,

$$1 - \ln(2) > 0$$

This is true since $\ln(x)$ is an increasing function and $1 < 2 < e$ implies

$$0 = \ln(1) < \ln(2) < \ln(e) = 1$$

Now look at the derivative

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{x+1}$$

We would like to show that $f'(x) \ge 0$ for $x > 1$, which means $f(x)$ is increasing and must therefore be positive for $x > 1$ (since it is already positive at $x=1$ per above).

Consider the following equivalent inequalities (when $x > 1$):

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{x+1} &\ge& 0\\
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} &\ge& \frac{1}{x+1}\\ 
x + 1 &\ge& 2\sqrt{x}                                   
\end{eqnarray}$$

For the last inequality, $1+1 = 2 = 2\sqrt{1}$ and for $x > 1$, taking the derivatives agains shows that the left side grows at a rate of $1$ and the right side grows at the rate of $\frac{2}{2\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} < 1$ when $x > 1$.

Thus the last equivalent inequality holds for $x > 1$, which implies $f'(x) \ge 0$ for $x > 1$ which implies $f(x)$ is positive for $x > 1$. In particular, $f(2) = \sqrt{2} - \ln(3) > 0$. Therefore $\sqrt{2} > \ln(3)$.

Answer (score 5):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$ \log(3) = \int_{0}^{2}\frac{dx}{1+x}\leq \sqrt{\int_{0}^{2}\frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}\int_{0}^{2}dx}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\tag{1}$$
and trivially $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}<\sqrt{2}$, hence $\color{red}{\log(3)<\sqrt{2}}$.
The same approch shows that for any $t>0$ we have
$$ \log(t+1) < \frac{t}{\sqrt{t+1}}\tag{2} $$
$$ \log(t+1) < \frac{2\sqrt{t+1}-2}{(t+1)^{1/4}}\tag{3} $$
and the inequalities are pretty tight if $t$ is close to zero.
For instance, $(3)$ immediately proves $\color{red}{\log(4)<\sqrt{2}}$.

---

**Addendum**. A nice alternative is provided by Beuker-type integrals. We have $\log(3)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{4\,dx}{4-x^2}$ and
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{4x^4(1-x^2)^4}{4-x^2}\,dx = 1296\log(3)-\frac{109632}{77}\tag{4}$$
is bounded between $0$ and $\frac{1}{40}$. It follows that $\log(3)\approx \frac{2284}{2079}=[1; 10, 7, 14, 2]$ is clearly less than $\sqrt{2}=[1;2,2,2,2,\ldots]$, by using the typical notation for continued fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another series argument:

Use the fact that $\sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8} + \frac{x^3}{16} -\cdots$ and $\ln(2+x) = \ln 2 + \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8} + \frac{x^3}{24} \cdots$. The first expansion is obtained by successfully differentiating $(1+x)^n$ and substituting $0$ with $n = \frac{1}{2}$.

Then $\sqrt{2} - \ln 3$ equals:

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} \cdots \right) - \left(\ln2 
 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{24} \right)$$
$$=\frac{49}{48} - \ln 2$$

and approximating $\ln 2$ as $1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{7}{12}$, we have:

$$\frac{49}{48} - \frac{7}{12} = \frac{7}{16} $$

The Lagrange error bound for $\sqrt{1+x}$ is:

$$|R_n| ≤ \frac{|1/16|(1-0)^4}{4!} \Rightarrow |R_n| ≤ \frac{1}{384} (\approx 0.0026)$$

and the Lagrange error bound for $\ln(1+x)$ is:

$$|R_n| ≤ \frac{|1/24|(1-0)^4}{4!} \Rightarrow |R_n| ≤ \frac{1}{576} (\approx 0.0017)$$

Meanwhile, the maximum error for approximating $\ln 2$ to order $x^4$ is:

$$|R_n| ≤ \frac{|-1/4|(1-0)^5}{5!} \Rightarrow |R_n| ≤ \frac{1}{480} (\approx 0.0021)$$

In the worst possible scenario, adding up all these errors gets nowhere near $\frac{7}{16}$. Therefore $\sqrt{2} - \ln 3 > 0$ and $\sqrt{2} > \ln 3$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\exp(\sqrt 2)= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(\sqrt 2)^n}{n!}$, then, $\exp(\sqrt 2) \geq 1+\sqrt 2 + \frac{(\sqrt{2})^2}{2}=2+\sqrt 2  > 3$, then $\sqrt 2  > \ln 3$.